# how to create continuous fields in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table name "title" in my database that has two field named as "lower_bound" and "upper_bound". I want to create a trigger on it such as when trying to add a continuous range, automatically it append it to the previous row. For example consider we have two row in this table like the follow :

```
id | lower_bound | upper_bound
------------------------------
1  | 10          | 20
------------------------------
2  | 50          | 70
------------------------------
```

What I want is that if I insert a row with follow values:

lower_bound = 21
upper_bound = 30

Instead of inserting this row, I append it to the first row and update its field like the follow:

```
id | lower_bound | upper_bound
------------------------------
1  | 10          | 30
------------------------------
2  | 50          | 70
------------------------------
```

Is this possible with a trigger?

My solution was that I use BEFORE INSERT trigger and do my requirement checking and if it was update able then I update my row.

There were two problems:

1. I can't cancel inserting process without raising an error which is not what I want.
2. I can't change the value of inserted row id as updated row id.

Comment: You can't insert or update the same table you are updating or inserting with a trigger. If it was allowed you would end up in an infinite loop. You have to create a procedure to do so. It will insert/update your value then do what you need.

Comment: @JorgeCampos . if i use stored procedure then i cant get control on my table and i cant be sure that all of my table records are Comply with my standards.

Comment: You will have to create some sort of lock mechanism to do it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos can you explain it more or refer a refrence?

Comment: because as i know lock mechanism is used to handling  concurring transactions.

Comment: So... you don't have concurrent transactions?

Comment: @Vatev . no, for now my problem is not about concurency.

Comment: Then you don't need a lock mechanism, you just need to create the procedure and instead of call insert or update command you would call this procedure.

Comment: I can't quite think of the answer, but I'm not (yet) convinced by the arguments that suggest that it's not possible outside a sproc or transaction.

Comment: @pooyansalavaty I think you're trying to implement the design in the wrong place. What do you mean by you can't get control on your table? You should be taking the control by design, are there other routines that manipulates the same data?

Comment: I do not understand how to recognize `continuous range` and update proper record. Imagine, if i enter `lower_bound = 1` and `upper_bound = 90` should i delete existing 'ranges' and add new one? Sorry, but it looks like you're trying to mix `update` and `insert` statement...

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your schema?  Implement two tables: low_bound and high_bound referencing each other by key.  Create a materialized view on the join of the two tables.  Create a before insert trigger on the materialized view that implements the check and updates the low_bound and high_bound as required.

Comment: Thinking outside the box. Nice.